# Wordpress - Checar se mouse passou/clicou na imagem sem links

Tags: html5, wordpress, imagem, widget

Pesquisei muito já e não achei de forma alguma algo que sirva, preciso de algo no wordpress que rode no widget html, que em uma imagem comum sendo exibida sem link algum registre em algum lugar (fora dos olhos do usuário) se o mesmo passou o mouse/tocou a imagem. Esta necessidade vem devido ao Tier de escolha publicitaria.

Infelizmente não sou programador, mas com ajuda sempre resolvo, só preciso de entender uma forma, um caminho para fazer isso.